# Commas between two json object

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am creating a json file from pseudo xml format file. However I get commas between json object, which I don't want.

This is sample of what I get:

```
[{"a": a , "b": b } , {"a": a , "b": b }]
```

However I want this:

```
{"a": a , "b": b } {"a": a , "b": b }
```

It might not be a valid json but I want it that way so that I can shuffle it by doing:

```
shuf -n 100000 original.json > sample.json
```

otherwise, it will be just one big line of json

This is my code:

```
def read_html_file(file_name):
    f = open(file_name,"r", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    html = f.read()
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return parsed_html

def process_reviews(parsed_html):
    reviews = []
    for r in parsed_html.findAll('review'):
        review_text = r.find('review_text').text
        asin = r.find('asin').text
        rating = r.find('rating').text
        product_type = r.find('product_type').text
        reviewer_location = r.find('reviewer_location').text
        reviews.append({
            'review_text': review_text.strip(),
            'asin': asin.strip(),
            'rating': rating.strip(),
            'product_type': product_type.strip(),
            'reviewer_location': reviewer_location.strip()
        })

    return reviews

def write_json_file(file_name, reviews):
    with open('{f}.json'.format(f=file_name), 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(reviews, outfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-f', '--file_name',action="store", dest="file_name",
    help="name of the input html file to parse", default="positive.html")
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    file_name = options.file_name

    html = read_html_file(file_name)
    reviews_list = process_reviews(html)
    write_json_file(file_name,reviews_list)
```

The first [ ] is because of the `reviews = []`, and I can manually remove it but I also don't want commas between my json object.

Comment: if there was no comma, it would not be json

Comment: You can't do that. Do you want this purely for display? If you saved your file in that format it would be, basically, broken.

Comment: in addition to what @vidstige said, also, don't remove the [ and ] if you want it to be valid json

Comment: I have edited the question to explain why I want it that way

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for **is just not JSON**. [The standards](https://json-schema.org/specification.html), by definition, specify there has to be a comma between objects. You have two options to go forward:

1. Update your parser to match the standards (highly recommended).
2. For display purposes, or other internal processing you may have, in case you really want the structure you specified: capture the JSON object and transform it to something else, but please do not call it JSON, because it isn't.

Comment: I have edited the question to explain why I want it that way

Comment: Then you need to capture the JSON and then parse it as something useful for your purposes. Option 2.

Comment: @BlueMango you need to capture the JSON object and perform some custom text transformation. That is explained in my answer, and also in my comment above. If you think this answers the question please mark it as correct. If you want help with a text parser, I think it's a different question and you should post again

Answer (score 1):

There are a few concepts you're mixing on your question!

1. What you have is not a `dict`, but a `list` of `dicts`. 

2. You don't have a JSON, neither on your input element `list`, nor on your expected output

Now going for solution, if you want to simply `print` your objects without the `comma` separating them, so you only need to `print` all your elements list, what you can do with:

```
sample = [{"a": "a" , "b": "b" } , {"a": "a" , "b": "b" }]
print(" ".join([str(element) for element in sample]))
```

Now, if what you really want is to manipulate it as a JSON object, you have two options, using the `json` lib:

### Add each element from your `sample` as a Json and manipulate it individually

They are already formatted as Json, so you could manipulate them using the `json` lib to pretty print (`dumps`) as strings or any other manipulation:

```
import json    
for element in sample:
        print(json.dumps(element, indent = 4))
```

### Make your sample list become a Json

You can either add all your elements to a single `key`, let's say adding to a `key` called `elements`, what would be:

```
sample_json = {"elements": []}
for data in sample:
    sample_json["elements"].append(data)
# Output from sample_json
# {'elements': [{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}, {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}]}
```

Or you can add every single element to a different `key`. As an example, I'll create a counter and each number of the counter will define a different `key` for that specific `element`:

```
sample_json = {}
counter = 0
for data in sample:
    sample_json[counter] = data
    counter += 1
# Output from sample_json
# {0: {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}, 1: {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}}
```

You could use text `keys` as well, for this second case.